# Dynamically datasource with hibernate and netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, datasource, jndi

How I can create web application project which is loading the jndi datasource set in the server configuration? I want to make the web application independent from the server and the database. Is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You create the DataSource in your web/application server and expose it through JNDI
2. You configure the following hibernate property:

   ```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource</p>
   ```

This way the application is decoupled from the JNDI provider. Even the JNDI url can be configured using a Maven property, so switching to an application server (that uses a different JNDI resource pattern) is just a mater of adding a new Maven profile.

One better approach is to [set up the DataSource in your application configuration](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/).

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
...
properties.put("hibernate.connection.datasource", dataSource);
```

This way you can use any [connection pooling](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/) framework, like the fastest connection pooling framework, [HikariCP](https://web.archive.org/web/20190901221613/http://brettwooldridge.github.io:80/HikariCP/).

You can even set up DataSource proxies, like:

- [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), to log SQL queries with PreparedStatement parameters
- [FlexyPool](https://vladmihalcea.com/flexy-pool-reactive-connection-pooling/), to monitor connection pooling usage and adjust the pool size using adapting startegies